# Find the adjoint operator of $T_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $V=\mathscr{M}_n(C)$ with an inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{Tr}\,(AB^{*})$, $P$ be a fixed invertible matrix in $V$, and $T_P$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $T_{P}(A)=P^{-1}AP$. Find $T^{*}_{P}$, the adjoint operator of $T_P$.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation $T_{P}^*$ should satisfy
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(P^{-1}APB^*)=\langle T_P(A),B\rangle=\langle A,T_P^*(B)\rangle
=\mathrm{Tr}\big(A(T_P^*(B))^*\big),
$$
for all $A,B \in \mathscr M(\mathbb C)$.
But
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(P^{-1}APB^*)=\mathrm{Tr}(APB^*P^{-1})=\mathrm{Tr}\big(A((P^*)^{-1}BP^*)^*\big)=\langle A,T_{P^{*}}(B)\rangle,
$$
and hence the adjoint of the transformation $T_P$ is the transformation $T_{P^*}$.

Comment: the adjoint of $T_P$ is $T_{P^{*}}$?

Comment: That's right - I fixed it.

Comment: thx a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $Tr(P^{-1}\cdot (APB^*) )=Tr(A \cdot (PB^*P^{-1}))$. Now consider $\hat{T}: \hat{T}(B)=PB^*P^{-1}$...